# Python web request in unity3d webrequest

Tags: python, c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Here this is code of python about web request. Can we do this same python code with Unity3D webrequest.

Code.

```
import requests
r = requests.post(
    "https://api.deepai.org/api/torch-srgan",
    files={
        'image': open('/path/to/your/file.jpg', 'rb'),
    },
    headers={'api-key': '535d7326-c37f6105b0'}
)

print(r.json())
```

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-UploadingRawData.html

Comment: Can you help me web request  with this code please.....

Answer (score 0):

You would use a [`UnityWebRequest.Post`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.Post.html) using the overload that takes a [`List<IMultipartFormSection>`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.IMultipartFormSection.html) and actually use a [`MultipartFormFileSection`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.MultipartFormFileSection.html)

Should be something like

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("/path/to/your/file.jpg");
var data = new List<IMultipartFormSection>();
data.Add(new MultipartFormFileSection("image", bytes, "file.jpg", "image/jpeg"));

using(var request = UnityWebRequest.Post("https://api.deepai.org/api/torch-srgan"))
{
    request.SetRequestHeader("api-key", "535d...........");

    yield return request.SendWebRequest();

    if (request.result != UnityWebRequest.Result.Success)
    {
        Debug.Log(request.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Form upload complete!");
        Debug.Log(request.downloadHandler.text);
    }
}
```

---

Then for parsing the JSON result you can use e.g.

```
[Serializable]
public class Response
{
    public string id;
    public string output_url;
}
```

and then do

```
....

var response = JsonUtility.FromJson<Response>(request.downloadHandler.text);

Debug.Log(response.output_url);
```

Comment: Thank you so much... but how can I get printf(r.json)

Comment: I don't know python very well but I assume this would print the response right? The thing is in python the request is immediately sent and you wait until it is back. In Unity you only get the downloaded `text` response (see added last line)

Comment: Ok I will try and let you know. One more thing can I do something like with #if dll file is exists in unity. Cause file will download after build but can not build cause of missing error.

Comment: what exactly does the error say? [`File.ReadAllBytes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readallbytes#System_IO_File_ReadAllBytes_System_String_) is part of `using System.IO;` which should not be an issue

Comment: I got error on Post and Result  " post does not exist in unitywebrequest "

Comment: Are you sure it is `Post` and not `post` in your code? And which Unity version are you using? The `result` was added in Unity 2020

Comment: Yes its Post and am using 2019 but I will update it if its working with 2020. Is Post with 2019?. I have 2 option to make this thing so here is one more thig to complete my code------second thing-------Can I do something like with #if dll file is exists then unity will compile code else not. Cause file will download after build but I can not build cause of dll not found error.

Comment: @FanAt Oh but I just noted: It's a method! You use it via `request = UnityWebRequest.Post()` without `new`, sorry my bad!

Comment: In result I got id and output url. Can you tell me how can I get only url. Like when I made this thing with .dll file there was option to to get only url. How can I do this thing in it.

Comment: @FanAt in general please keep the scope of your question as minimal as possible and if you have follow up questions please start a new process of doing your research, try something and ask a new question here if you get stuck. For now see the update at the bottom of the answer